# What races have Spider Climb as a racial trait?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, racial-traits

What races have Spider Climb as a racial trait according to official WotC materials? I know Chitine have it, but who else?

Comment: Asking for lists of things doesn't work well here, because the site is optimised for solving problems, not compiling lists. You haven't told us anything about the problem you're trying to solve. Why do you want a list of Spider Climb-ing races? What problem do you have, that would/might be solved by having such a list?

Answer (score 2):

### Explicit Listings

The [vampire](http://www.dndsrd.net/monstersTtoZ.html#vampire) and hooded pupil *(Libris Mortis, p109)* templates provide [*spider climb*](http://www.dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#spider-climb).

Looking it up, I find that the Katane template (half-vampire, *Dragon Magazine #313, p64*), also gets *spider climb*.

These races have Limited versions of *spider climb*: Immoth *(Monster Manual II, p128)* and [white dragons](http://www.dndsrd.net/monstersDrtoDw.html#white-dragon) get Icewalking (*spider climb* on ice and snow), and [copper dragons](http://www.dndsrd.net/monstersDrtoDw.html#white-dragon) and sapphire dragons *(Monster Manual II, p84)* get *spider climb* on stone.

Each of these are Extraordinary abilities, except the hooded pupil's, which is Supernatural.

---

#### Other options

Since the chitine can climb 'as if under the effect of a *spider climb* spell', and has a listed climb speed, these races, which gain a climb speed instead, *may* bear consideration as well (although *spider climb* is better than a mere climb speed, due to not requiring climb checks):

The forestkith *(Monster Manual III, p64)* [jungle](http://www.dndsrd.net/unearthedEnvironmentalVariants.html#jungle-goblins) and snow *(Frostburn, p136)* goblins have a 20' climb speed (jungle goblin is LA +0 and *it* can use Dexterity rather than strength for climb checks). The grippli (Dragon Magazine #324, p87) has a 20' climb speed as well. The arachnoid and chameleon creature templates *(Underdark, p80, 83)* gain a climb speed, as does the Nimble Skeleton template *(Libris Mortis, p162)*. The nether hound template *(Dragon Magazine #322, p89)* also gains a climb speed.

Comment: Climb speeds are different from *spider climb*, and there are a lot more options for getting one, probably too many to list as an aside.

Comment: @KRyan Alright. Those were the *races* that I found granting climb. I didn't mention [ape barbarian](http://www.dndsrd.net/unearthedCoreClass.html#ape-totem), for example, just races, since that's what the querent specified. Too much?